# If logged edit content: SQL statement in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I've a content page, and when I've submitted a content and the url page is for example:
`category.php?nameID=Categoryname&id=25`

In the script I'm checking if the right user is logged in who submitted this content.

If the same guy submitted this content and he goes to the submitted content page he will receive on the top of the page this text:

`Edit this post`  I'm using 2 different tables one is called `users` where all register users are in and the row for calling a user is `username`. The second table is called `post` and the row is called `add` where you can find the username inside.

So when `user.username` & `post.add` are equal for ex. username `admin` also this script checks if you are logged in as `admin`

I'm getting this error:
`Unknown column 'admin' in 'where clause'`

```
    if($user->isLoggedIn()) {
    $pakuser = $user->data()->username;
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN post ON users.username = post.add WHERE post.id = $id AND post.add = $pakuser") or die(mysql_error());
    if ($sql === FALSE) {
    }
    $row    = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    if($row['add'])
    {           
    echo '<p>edit this post</p>';
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't add 'Solved' to question titles, accept the answer that helped you instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need quotes around the string value:

```
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users 
                        INNER JOIN post ON users.username = post.add 
                        WHERE post.id = $id AND post.add = '$pakuser'")
           or die(mysql_error());
```

You should look into upgrading to mysqli or PDO and using parametrized queries instead of string substitution.

Comment: Thank you very much! Its working, yes I know I'm also watching tutorials about PDO I've made my login script with PDO thanks anyway